# How to split Nest.js microservices into separate projects?

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices, nestjs

Let's say I want to create a simplistic cinema-management platform. It needs few microservices: `movies`, `cinemas`, `payments`, etc.

How would you go about doing it in Nest.js? I don't want them in the same big folder as that feels like making a monolith. I want them to be separate Nest.js projects with their own git repositories so I can orchestrate them with Kubernetes later on.

How? How to connect from service `cinemas` to service `movies` if they are two separate projects and only share, let's say, Redis?

Edit:
This is not a question about microservices in general. This is a question Nest.js specific. I read the documentation, I know there are decorators like `@Client` for connecting to the transport layer. I just want to know where to use that decorator and maybe see a short snippet of code on "having two separate Nest.js repositories how to connect them together so they can talk to each other".

I don't care about the transport layer, that thing I can figure out myself. I just need some advice on the framework itself as I believe the documentation is lacking.

Comment: the microservices should not share any database and should communicate only using the network (HTTP, messaging etc)

Comment: @JesseCarter "let's say Redis" is pointing to a specific transport layer. "Did you even read the docs" - please don't insult me. Of course I did. I still think the documentation is lacking in example on how to take one microservice and use `@Client` (or something) to connect to different one. The sample in GitHub (`3-microservices`) is using only one project and is a hybrid app. That's why I posted here.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu yes, they shouldn't share a database. That's why I want them as seperate as they can be. Nest.js supports multiple different transport layers including `Transport.REDIS`. That was just an example.

Comment: I can't give you an answer because I don't use Nest.js but I could share with you some thoughts. So, the microservices should communicate only using the network, using a protocol that hides the technologies that are used by the other. So, if a microservice uses Nest.js (or another framework) it should not assume that the other microservice uses also Nest.js. And also, when a microservice processes a request, it should not ask for data from another microservice during that request *if you want resilience*; in other words, it should have all the data already gathered from other microservice.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I know how microservices work. I need to use Nest.js for microservices though and I don't grasp how to utilize their decorators. This is a Nest.js specific question (hence the tag). It's not the architecture I'm asking for but an example of two Nest.js microservices that can talk to one another but are in separate two Nest.js projects.

Comment: I understand now, +1 from me

Comment: I can see that the actual microservices example doesn't show multiple services.This is definitely still outside the scope of a StackOverflow question though. If you put a bounty on it I'll put together a git repo that you can use as reference material

Comment: Good stuff! Glad you figured out how to put things together. After you asked this I decided to put together an example repo anyways. It's pretty barebones at the moment but provides a GraphQL client application that communicates with another microservice over Redis. Set up with all kinds of docker and docker-compose goodness so that people can reference a working example: https://github.com/WonderPanda/nestjs-microservice-architecture

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I got it working. Basically the way to do it is to create two separate projects. Let's say - one is a `createMicroservice` and another is just an HTTP app (but could easily be another microservice). I used a "normal" app just so I can call it easily for testing.

Here is the `main.ts` file that creates microservice.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Transport } from '@nestjs/common/enums/transport.enum';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: {
      url: 'redis://localhost:6379',
    },
  });
  await app.listen(() => console.log('MoviesService is running.'));
}
bootstrap();
```

And one of the controllers:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @MessagePattern({ cmd: 'LIST_MOVIES' })
  listMovies(): string[] {
    return ['Pulp Fiction', 'Blade Runner', 'Hatred'];
  }
}
```

Now - in the microservice you declare to what kinds of events should controllers react to (`@MessagePattern`). While in the "normal" service you do this in the controller when you want to ask other microservices for something (the `main.ts` is the simplest example that you get when you create a new project using `@nestjs/cli`.

The controller code:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  private readonly client: ClientProxy;

  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {
    this.client = ClientProxyFactory.create({
      transport: Transport.REDIS,
      options: {
        url: 'redis://localhost:6379',
      },
    });
  }

  @Get()
  listMovies() {
    const pattern = { cmd: 'LIST_MOVIES' };

    return this.client.send<string[]>(pattern, []);
  }
}
```

So as long a `client` is connected to the same transport layer as the microservice - they can talk to each other by using the `@MessagePattern`.

For nicer code you can move the `this.client` part from a constructor to a provider and then use dependency injection by declaring the provider in the module.

Comment: You might want to consider using Nats instead of Redis so that you can continue to use pub/sub with multiple nodes/instances of the same service (i.e. you only want one of them to handle a given message.  think user login, or data manipulation).  Nats allows you to add the same services/modules to their own queue so only one instance of a given service picks up a message.